# Duplicate Title Tag even though names are different - htaccess rule issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have 4 URLS that are being reported as having duplicate content:

https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M100

https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M1000

...both the above resolve to the i8-M100 page NOT the i8-M1000

and

https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M70

https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M700

...both the above resolve to the i8-M70 page NOT the i8-M700

.htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule medical-incinerator/I8-M70 page.php?ProductID=31&ProductType=6
RewriteRule medical-incinerator/I8-M700 page.php?ProductID=35&ProductType=1
RewriteRule medical-incinerator/I8-M100 page.php?ProductID=33&ProductType=6
RewriteRule medical-incinerator/I8-M1000 page.php?ProductID=36&ProductType=6
```

I'm pretty sure this is my rules in .htaccess, and i'm pretty sure I need a variable/marker to declare the end of the URL?

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm guessing i've either done something wrong or it is just a subject no-one particularly enjoys answering? Either way hoping for some feedback,

Oddly if I try  https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M70000000000 this also resolves to the https://www.inciner8.com/medical-incinerator/I8-M70 URL. 

Its almost as if its ignoring anything after the first matched part of the URL?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ive renamed the products, as I got complete zero responses from here?